# How to load index shards by gensim.similarities.Similarity？

Tags: python, gensim

I'm working on something using gensim.

In gensim, var `index` usually means an object of `gensim.similarities.<cls>`.

At first, I use `gensim.similarities.Similarity(filepath, ...)` to save index as a file, and then loads it by `gensim.similarities.Similarity.load(filepath + '.0')`. Because `gensim.similarities.Similarity` default save index to shards file like `index.0`.

When index file becoming larger, it automatically seperate into more shards, like `index.0`,`index.1`,`index.2`......

How can I load these shards file? `gensim.similarities.Similarity.load()` can only load one file.

BTW: I have try to find the answer in gensim's doc, but failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
from gensim.corpora.textcorpus import TextCorpus
from gensim.test.utils import datapath, get_tmpfile
from gensim.similarities import Similarity

temp_fname = get_tmpfile("index")
output_fname = get_tmpfile("saved_index")
corpus = TextCorpus(datapath('testcorpus.txt'))
index = Similarity(output_fname, corpus, num_features=400)

index.save(output_fname)
loaded_index = index.load(output_fname)
```

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/similarities/docsim.html

Comment: This isn't a good answer. It still doesn't provide a working example of loading multiple shards.

Comment: I should be more specific. How does one deal with the model, index, etc. Gensim files being moved from one server to another on the reload? Things like the output_prefix don't change upload load. They're still the same as where the model was saved. How will this affect adding more shard files?

Comment: u can check the option check_moved() function after loading index.

Answer (score 0):

shoresh's answer is correct. The key part that OP was missing was 
    index.save(output_fname)

While just creating the object *appears* to save it, it's really only saving the shards, which require saving a sort of directory file (via index.save(output_fname) to be made accessible as a whole object.